# can i use LiveData in Room SELECT Query (not as a return type)

Tags: android, android-room

can I do something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM DataClassPost WHERE documentPath IN (:docsList) ORDER BY postTime DESC")
    fun subscribeToCollectionDocs(docsList: LiveData<List<String>>): LiveData<List<DataClassPost>>
```

or I have to use `List<String>`?

Answer (score 0):

No you cant refer to the live data inside the QUERY. just pass the String itself from the live data value to the function so your function would look like
`fun subscribeToCollectionDocs(docsList: String): LiveData<List<DataClassPost>>`

Comment: I'm already using `fun subscribeToCollectionDocs(docsList: List<String>): LiveData<List<DataClassPost>>` and it is working normally, but beside it, I have to write more functions and observers to achieve my goal

Comment: Alright then, so according to your original question - you cant refer to a live data inside the QUERY :)